# Flash communicates with camera but does not fire

Tags: flash, yongnuo, canon-70d

I have a canon 70D and a yongnuo speedlight YN568EX II. When I first unboxed it from new I was able to just slip on the hotshoe of my camera and fire away. For some reason, it stopped firing.The flash behaves likes normal, communicates with the camera and everything, but does not fire. I've tried tons of setting to get it firing but hasn't been successful.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Does the flash fire when you press the "Pilot" button?

Comment: Have you try with fresh batteries?

Comment: Hi Andy and Romeo, the flash doesn't fire when I hit the Pilot button but all communication between camera and flash works fine. I put new batteries on but still no luck. I haven't used the flash for more than a day and that was when I was going through the functions...

Comment: Is the flash connected to the camera when you use the pilot button? Also, are you using the camera in Liveview mode, as I believe that Liveview silent shooting modes in the camera disable the flash functionality

Comment: I have the same problem. The pilot button works but when I shoot a image with the flash turned on and red light on it doesn't fire.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you got a bad unit.  I'd say return/exchange it.  If it's not firing from the Pilot button when full charged with known good batteries, then it could be an issue with the capacitor or the flash tube, and that's pretty major.

Yongnuo gear has a lot of happy customers, but if you go back through the history of their stuff, you'll find that copy consistency and component quality has been an issue with them in the past--the low price has to come from *somewhere*. DOA units that would fire once or twice and then blow their capacitors were not uncommon back in the early days of the YN-565EX (just [google "YN-565EX capacitor failure"](https://www.google.com/search?q=YN-565EX%20capacitor%20failure)).  While YN's QA has gotten much better over time, they're still not at the level of OEM reliability.

Answer (score 0):

It just may be your camera settings. I was having this problem, it would not flash when triggered by my camera but when I pushed the pilot button it did. I had tried changing batteries before this but with brand new batteries it still was not working. I really didn't think there was anything wrong with the flash. I changed my shutter speed and "boom"- it worked!

Comment: The OP sais in the comment that the flash doesn't fire when he hit the Pilot button.

Answer (score -1):

There are settings inside the camera. where you can fire the AF assist beam, without firing the flash, so that it enables the camera to focus better in dark situations.   [AF ASSIST BEAM AND FLASH FIRING](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/exploring-flash-control-options-on-your-canon-eos-.html)

Comment: Could you elaborate a little ? You are redirecting to another website for the answer, which might not be helpful if this website goes down and the page removed.